# Trying to add a form to a DetailView

Tags: python, django

I am writing a Detail View - and the form that is displayed is the particular Track that the user is adding/updating to the CD Entry (It's a CD Library application). The trick is I want to see everything else about the CD on the page as well as the form for the particular track. Having trouble figuring out how to get the form to be just the trac I am adding/updating.

Basically you can enter a CD Title,Artist, and total time of the CD into the CD model.  Then the Tracks are stored in the Track Model, with their Foreign Key being the CD they are on.

While looking at a Detail View of the CD, the user can add or update a Particular track via a button.  I'm trying to get the update part working.
Model Looks like this:

```
from django.db import models

from datetime import datetime, timedelta

class Cd(models.Model):
  artist_name    = models.CharField(max_length=155)
  cd_title       = models.CharField(max_length=155)
  cd_total_time           = models.TimeField(default="00:00:00")
  cd_total_time_delta     = models.DurationField(default=timedelta)
  cd_run_time         = models.TimeField(default="00:00:00",blank=True)
  cd_run_time_delta   = models.DurationField(default=timedelta)
  cd_remaining_time       = models.TimeField(default="00:00:00",blank=True)
  cd_remaining_time_delta = models.DurationField(default=timedelta)

  def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().save(*args,**kwargs)

  def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.artist_name} : {self.cd_title}"

class Track(models.Model):
  cd_id = models.ForeignKey(Cd, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    related_name='cd_tracks',
  )
  track_title   = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  track_number  = models.IntegerField()
  trk_length_time     = models.TimeField(null=True,default=None, blank=True)
  trk_length_time_delta = models.DurationField(default=timedelta)
  trk_run_time         = models.TimeField(default="00:00:00",blank=True)
  trk_run_time_delta   = models.DurationField(default=timedelta)
  trk_remaining_time       = models.TimeField(default="00:00:00",blank=True)
  trk_remaining_time_delta = models.DurationField(default=timedelta)

  def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
      super().save(*args,**kwargs)
      self.cd_id.save()

  def __str__(self):
      return f"{self.track_title}"
```

The views.py snippet:

```
class Track_update(UpdateView):
  model = Track
  template_name = 'track_update.html'
  fields = [ 'cd_id', 'track_title',
        'track_number', 'trk_length_time'
  ]
  success_url = "/"

class Cd_DetailView(DetailView):
  model = Cd
  template_name = 'cd_detail.html'
  fields = ['artist_name','cd_title','cd_total_time',
    'cd_run_time','cd_remaining_time'
  ]

class Cd_MixedView(FormMixin, DetailView):
  model = Cd
  template_name = 'cd_mixed_view.html'
  form_class = TrackForm

  def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse('cd_detail {id}')

  def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(Cd_MixedView,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['form'] = TrackForm(initial={
        'cd_id':self.object
    })
    return context

  def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.object = self.get_object()
    form = self.get_form()

    if form.is_valid():
      return self.form_valid(form)
    else:
      return self.form_invalid(form)

  def form_valid(self,form):
    form.save()
    return super(Cd_MixedView, self).form_valid(form)
```

The urls.py looks like

```
from django.urls import path

from django.contrib import admin


from .views import (
  HomePageView,
  Cd_Create,
  Cd_Update,
  Cd_DetailView,
  List_Cds,
  Track_Create,
  Cd_MixedView,
)

urlpatterns = [
  path('', HomePageView.as_view(), name = 'home'),
  path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
  path('cd/add/', Cd_Create.as_view(), name='cd_new'),
  path('cd/update/<int:pk>', Cd_Update.as_view(), name='cd_update'),
  path('cd/detail/<int:pk>', Cd_DetailView.as_view(), name='cd_detail'),
  path('track/add/', Track_Create.as_view(), name='track_new'),
  path('track/add/<int:pk>', Cd_MixedView.as_view(), name='cd_mixed_view'),
  path('list/', List_Cds.as_view(), name='list_cds'),
]
```

The template looks like this:

```
<!-- templates/cd_mixed_view.html -->
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block title %} CD Details{% endblock title %}
{% block content %}
<h1>CD Update Track </h1>

<p>Artist Name:&nbsp;{{ cd.artist_name}}
<p>Cd Title:&nbsp;{{ cd.cd_title }}
<p>Cd Total Time:&nbsp;{{ cd.cd_total_time|time:"H:i:s" }}
<p>Cd Run Time:&nbsp;{{ cd.cd_run_time|time:"H:i:s" }}
<p>Cd Remaining Time:&nbsp;
{% if cd.cd_run_time_delta > cd.cd_total_time_delta %}
   (-{{ cd.cd_remaining_time|time:"H:i:s" }})
{% else %}
   {{ cd.cd_remaining_time|time:"H:i:s" }}
{% endif %}
<TABLE BORDER="0" TABLE_LAYOUT="fixed" WIDTH="100%">
  <TR BGCOLOR="#B0B0FF">
    <TD></TD>
    <TD ALIGN="Center">&nbsp;Track #</TD>
    <TD ALIGN="Center"> Cut Title</TD>
    <TD ALIGN="Center">Track Length</TD>
    <TD ALIGN="Center" BGCOLOR="#CC99CC">Run Time</TD>
    <TD ALIGN="Center" BGCOLOR="#CC99CC">Time Remaining</TD>
  </TR>
      {% for tracks in cd.cd_tracks.all %}
  *** This is the part I am having trouble with ***
      {% if tracks.id = track number that was clicked %}
         {form_as_p}
      {% else %}
      <TR>
        <TD ALIGN="Center" rowspan="1" height="33" width="33">
        <TD ALIGN="Left" VALIGN="Top" WIDTH="10">&nbsp;{{ tracks.track_number }}</TD>
        <TD ALIGN="Left" VALIGN="Top">&nbsp;{{ tracks.track_title }}</TD>
        <TD ALIGN="Left" VALIGN="Top">{{ tracks.trk_length_time|time:"H:i:s" }}</TD>
        <TD ALIGN="Left" VALIGN="Top">{{ tracks.trk_run_time|time:"H:i:s" }}</TD>
        {% if tracks.trk_run_time_delta > cd.cd_total_time_delta %}
          <TD BGCOLOR="#8DF1BF" ALIGN="Left">&nbsp;(-{{ tracks.trk_remaining_time|time:"H:i:s" }})</TD>
        {% else %}
          <TD BGCOLOR="#8DF1BF" ALIGN="Left">&nbsp;{{ tracks.trk_remaining_time|time:"H:i:s" }}</TD>
        {% endif %}
      </TR>
      {% endfor %}
      </TABLE>
  </table>
{% endblock content %}
```

So, how do I pass the Track ID into the template, so that I can display the form for THAT track, otherwise
display the track information for all the other tracks.

Any information about how to approach this would be greatly appreciated.
Below is a picture of what the Detail Screen looks like before attempting to update the Track.
[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you think about adding the tracking id as a slug, creating another function in views, to pass it? with an 'a' tag, and passing an href, with inside it the foreign key if the track referring to the CD. You could pass the values in the context of the view.

Comment: Have never used slugs before so not sure what that looks like (new to Django). But I also dont know if I need one since technically at this point I already know the CD primary key and the track ID. If creating it then I don't have the Track ID, but could call the create function instead of update functionality...?